# Dining Philosopher's Solution needed

Tags: java

I'm stuck on implementing a solution in Java for Dining Philosopher's problem.

The error I'm getting is

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
>       at Main.main(Main.java:43)"
>
> That line 43 is:

```
rFork = forks[forI + 1];
```

> and is within the for loop below

```
for (int i = 0; i < phiNum; i++)
        {
            list[i] = new Philosopher(forks[i], forks[(i + 1) % phiNum], 
                    i, in.nextFloat());
            for (int forI = 0; forI < (phiNum); forI++)
            {
                lFork = forks[forI];
                rFork = forks[forI + 1];
            }
        }
```

Below is the rest of my code for the Main.java class:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
   static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int phiNum = 0, maxForks = 2;
      float time = 0;

      System.out.print("Enter the number of Philosophers: ");
      phiNum = in.nextInt();

      //float timeSpentThinking = in.nextFloat();
      Philosopher[] list = new Philosopher[phiNum];
      Fork[] forks = new Fork [phiNum];
      Fork lFork = new Fork();
      Fork rFork = new Fork();

      if (phiNum == 0)
         System.out.println("There are no philosophers eating or 
            thinking.");
      else if (phiNum == 1)
         System.out.println("There are not enough forks for the 
            philosopher" + " to eat.");
      else
      {
         for (int index = 0; index < (phiNum); index++)
            forks[index] = new Fork();
         for (int i = 0; i < phiNum; i++)
         {
            list[i] = new Philosopher(forks[i], forks[(i + 1) % phiNum], 
                    i, in.nextFloat());
            for (int forI = 0; forI < (phiNum); forI++)
            {
               lFork = forks[forI];
               rFork = forks[forI + 1];
            }
         }
      }
      for (int i = 1; i < list.length; i++)
         list[i].run();
   }
}
```

Comment: `forNum = 0;` and `Fork[] forks = new Fork [forNum];` Do you see something you might need to change? Are you maybe missing the code to enter a number of forks, in the same manner you enter a number of philosophers?

Answer (score 0):

You declare this variable:

```
forNum = 0;
```

And use it to declare the array:

```
Fork[] forks = new Fork [forNum];
```

So the array is empty, so trying to access it gives you the error. You would have to either give the variable `forNum` a value other than zero, or ask the user to enter the number of forks:

```
System.out.print("Enter the number of forks: ");
forNum = in.nextInt();
```

Learning to use a debugger would have helped you to see that the array was of size zero.

Comment: Well, forNum has to be set equal to phiNum because in the problem setup the numbers of philosophers must be equal to that of forks.  So I changed the instantiation of forks to use phiNum, instead of forNum.  Still having issues with the for loop though.

Comment: @Jeff Did you change `Fork[] forks = new Fork [forNum];` to `Fork[] forks = new Fork [phiNum];`, or something else? Is the error message exactly the same, or is the index different? (I ask because the way the loop is set up, you will be going past the last index, and you may need to have the loop condition as `(phiNum - 1)` instead).

Comment: I did change Fork[] forks  = new Fork[forNum]; to Fork[] forks = new Fork[phiNum];.  
There currently is an error with the line
rFork = forks[forI + 1];

I'll edit my original post to include more clear code, hopefully that might help.

Comment: Problem now is that with `for (int forI = 0; forI < (phiNum); forI++)` in conjuncture with `rFork = forks[forI + 1];` mens that on the last iteration, you'll go out of bounds, past the last element in the array. Try using the condition `forI < (phiNum-1)` instead.

Comment: Ok, that did help, I don't have that error anymore.  But evidently there's something wrong with my run() method in the Philosopher class still because I'm not getting any actual output.@AntonH

Comment: @Jeff That's probably best for another question.